# Can a large drop in the PSD indicate the presence of a periodic noise?

Tags: fourier-transform, noise, power-spectral-density, fourier

I was wondering if a large drop in the plot of the PSD of a sensor measurement could indicate the presence of a periodic noise.

Here is my PSD:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting a sensor floor at about $10^{-7} V^2/Hz$

Comment: Where is the large drop?  If you mean the downward spikes, like the one going almost down to $10^{-11}$, that's almost certainly an artifact of the data and the calculation -- try taking the data again and running the same calculation.  If the spike disappears, or moves, then it's an artifact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not an inference you can make.

Anything periodic would, on the contrary, lead to spikes in the PSD.